# Uable to print after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 (HP MFC-7470DW)

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, brother, cups-lpd

I just upgraded my system from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Since the upgrade i'm unable to print on my Brother MFC-J470DW.
The printer is found when pluged in (USB). But when I sent a test print (or any other document) it briefly appears in the printers job list and finishes after a few seconds, showing a successfull job in the job list.

Scanning on the other hand works fine, from the bed and from the feeder.

I've been searching the internet for a few days but nothing worked so far.

I tried reinstalling the drivers from the command line a few times after removing the printer using the CUPS webinterface, by using Settings-->Printers and using the uninstall tool from brother from the command line.

Also tried the procedure Blacklisting the `usblp` module.

One thing maybe worth mentioning is that in 16.04 I had added a link lpd to cups in the /etc/init.d directory. That was the fix for me on 16.04 but this doesn't do the trick anymore.)

output `dmesg`:

```
[120902.496158] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[120902.609557] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04f9, idProduct=02e8
[120902.609559] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[120902.609560] usb 1-1.2: Product: MFC-J470DW
[120902.609562] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: Brother
[120902.609563] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: BROM3F156149
[120902.612364] usblp 1-1.2:1.0: usblp1: USB Bidirectional printer dev 13 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x04F9 pid 0x02E8
```

`lsusb` information:

```
$ lsusb | grep Brother
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 04f9:02e8 Brother Industries, Ltd
```

permssions seem to be correct:

```
$ ls -l /dev/bus/usb/001/013
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root lp 189, 12 Oct 11 11:38 /dev/bus/usb/001/013
```

also after unplugging and reconnecting the connection might change but cleanup and create seems correct with the right permissions.

Any ideas what to try next?

Another [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082292/18-04-and-brother-mfc-7420-usb-printer-doesnt-print) seems to be linked to this, same problems different printer.

update:

After some uninstalling and reinstalling new drivers, with different conditions like installing while printer is not/is connected, using different driver versions the printer is still not working.

some things I noticed (might or might not be relevant):

- synaptic package manager show printer drivers as being 0 Kb
- raw print to /dev/usb/lpx makes the printer wake-up, showing the message 'recieving' with some progress markers but even then it won't print.

I'm sure i'm using the same drivers as in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, still using CUPS albeit different version, still linking init.d/lpd to init.d/cups, checked and rechecked all requirements from Brother.

Update:

After some serious digging and testing I think i narrowed the issue for my printing issues to some file not found issues.

Note the icc profile not found errors in the error_log. 
I don't know what it's needed for or what it does but seems like an issue.

```
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======BRHalfTonePattern=Diffusion BRMonoColor=Mono number-up=1 BRJpeg=Recommended BRDuplex=DuplexNoTumble noCollate PageSize=A4 BRColorMatching=Vivid BRContrast=0 BRBlue=0 BRColorEnhancement=OFF BRBrightness=0 BRGreen=0 BRMediaType=PlainDuplex BRDuplexMode=Normal BRSlowDrying=OFF BRColorPaperThick=Regular BRResolution=PlainNormal BRRed=0 BRBiDir=ON job-uuid=urn:uuid:3fcd853a-cee3-3cab-7b08-d5391119cf43 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1539641635 time-at-processing=1539644988 Copies=1
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======BRContrast=
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======-cont
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======-cont
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======BRHalfTonePattern=Diffusion BRMonoColor=Mono number-up=1 BRJpeg=Recommended BRDuplex=DuplexNoTumble noCollate PageSize=A4 BRColorMatching=Vivid BRContrast=0 BRBlue=0 BRColorEnhancement=OFF BRBrightness=0 BRGreen=0 BRMediaType=PlainDuplex BRDuplexMode=Normal BRSlowDrying=OFF BRColorPaperThick=Regular BRResolution=PlainNormal BRRed=0 BRBiDir=ON job-uuid=urn:uuid:3fcd853a-cee3-3cab-7b08-d5391119cf43 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1539641635 time-at-processing=1539644988 Copies=1
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======BRRed=
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======-red
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======-red
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======BRHalfTonePattern=Diffusion BRMonoColor=Mono number-up=1 BRJpeg=Recommended BRDuplex=DuplexNoTumble noCollate PageSize=A4 BRColorMatching=Vivid BRContrast=0 BRBlue=0 BRColorEnhancement=OFF BRBrightness=0 BRGreen=0 BRMediaType=PlainDuplex BRDuplexMode=Normal BRSlowDrying=OFF BRColorPaperThick=Regular BRResolution=PlainNormal BRRed=0 BRBiDir=ON job-uuid=urn:uuid:3fcd853a-cee3-3cab-7b08-d5391119cf43 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1539641635 time-at-processing=1539644988 Copies=1
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======BRGreen=
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======-green
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======-green
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======BRHalfTonePattern=Diffusion BRMonoColor=Mono number-up=1 BRJpeg=Recommended BRDuplex=DuplexNoTumble noCollate PageSize=A4 BRColorMatching=Vivid BRContrast=0 BRBlue=0 BRColorEnhancement=OFF BRBrightness=0 BRGreen=0 BRMediaType=PlainDuplex BRDuplexMode=Normal BRSlowDrying=OFF BRColorPaperThick=Regular BRResolution=PlainNormal BRRed=0 BRBiDir=ON job-uuid=urn:uuid:3fcd853a-cee3-3cab-7b08-d5391119cf43 job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1539641635 time-at-processing=1539644988 Copies=1
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======BRBlue=
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] DATA======-blue
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] search_data======-blue
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_gray.icc 
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] | ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2261: gsicc_init_iccmanager(): cannot find default icc profile
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] ./base/gsicc_manage.c:1244: gsicc_open_search(): Could not find default_rgb.icc 
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] | ./base/gsicc_manage.c:2025: gsicc_set_device_profile(): cannot find device profile
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] **** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] Sent 0 bytes...
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] PID 9992 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_mfcj470dw) exited with no errors.
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:48 +0200] [Job 6] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:49 +0200] [Job 6] PID 9993 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:49 +0200] [Job 6] time-at-completed=1539644988
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:49 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [16/Oct/2018:01:09:49 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
I [16/Oct/2018:01:09:49 +0200] [Job 6] Job completed.
I [16/Oct/2018:01:09:49 +0200] Expiring subscriptions...
```

so the job passes through the usb quircks and the different filters but fails on finding the icc profiles
I'm not knowledgeable enough to deduct and let alone fix the issue but maybe someone could tell me if i'm on the right path or missing the issue completely?

there are a bunch of icc profile on the disk but either some search path isn't set correctly or I'm missing some required packages.
Here I'm completely stuck; anyone able to give me a direction on how to continue the research?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080720/printer-filter-failed/1080926#1080926) which worked for some:

```
sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common
```

But it didn't work for me with Brother DCP-7065DN printer after fresh [cloning of 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028604/bash-script-to-clone-ubuntu-to-new-partition-for-testing-18-04-lts-upgrade/1028605#1028605) and upgrade to 18.04 on October 14, 2018.

### After reboot works

Purging the ghost scripts works, but not until you reboot. Then **even before you sign on**, everything that failed to print previously, suddenly prints out.

**This is a huge security issue!** Imagine a manager tries to print sensitive documents after 18.04 upgrade and it fails. The manager gives up and goes off to call Tech Support. Another user reboots the computer and even before they sign on the manager's reports spit out for the unauthorized employee to see.

After initial reboot I was able to print normally.

### Others with similar problems

Many people are having problems printing after 16.04 to 18.04 upgrade:

- [Printer "Filter failed"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080720/printer-filter-failed/1080926#1080926)
- [printers not working after distribution upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1080558/printers-not-working-after-distribution-upgrade)
- [Printer stopped working after upgrade 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081885/printer-stopped-working-after-upgrade-16-04-to-18-04)
- [Ubuntu 18.04: Printer not working for most apps (PDF, evince, Firefox...)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036429/ubuntu-18-04-printer-not-working-for-most-apps-pdf-evince-firefox)
- [Printer stopped working after upgrade 16.04 to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081885/printer-stopped-working-after-upgrade-16-04-to-18-04?rq=1)
- [Brother Printer printing garbage after upgrade to 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1076529/brother-printer-printing-garbage-after-upgrade-to-18-04)
- [Epson RX620 not printing since upgrade to 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1075136/epson-rx620-not-printing-since-upgrade-to-18-04-lts?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS -- Printing Service Not Available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065068/ubuntu-18-04-lts-printing-service-not-available)
- [Upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS now cannot print](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085872/upgraded-to-ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-now-cannot-print)

Answer (score 0):

This was it, thanks for this answer. it was just what I needed.

Checked the /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles directory; it was empty.
Executed the command just like the doctor ordered:

```
sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common
```

Tried to to run a test-print. check it worked.

for reference the last few entries of the Job:

```
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Read 8192 bytes of print data...
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Wrote 8192 bytes of print data...
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Read 3552 bytes of print data...
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Wrote 3552 bytes of print data...
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Sent 2130460 bytes...
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] PID 13368 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_mfcj470dw) exited with no errors.
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Waiting for read thread to exit...
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] PID 13369 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/usb) exited with no errors.
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] time-at-completed=1539687822
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] cupsdMarkDirty(----S)
D [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] cupsdSetBusyState: newbusy="Printing jobs and dirty files", busy="Printing jobs and dirty files"
I [16/Oct/2018:13:03:42 +0200] [Job 8] Job completed.
```

pitty I can't mark your answer as usefull (reputation too low).