# Printing using new version of ubuntu

Tags: printing

I upgraded to version 18.04, and now cannot print. I am able to scan documents, but not print. I have restarted both printer & computer a number of times, as well as removed and re-added the printer, but it still does not work.
My printer is HP Office jet Pro 6830 and I'm using Linux

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to print on Brother MFC-j470DW Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1082892/unable-to-print-on-brother-mfc-j470dw-ubuntu-18-04-lts)

Comment: I have a HP Office Jet Pro 6830 printer

Comment: The model of printer is not relevant. Read it and see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) - follow last sentence of the answer (`sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`).

Comment: @N0rbert I'm familiar with the link like you are. In this case the HP printer was working in 16.04 but broke after 18.04 upgrade. Is that covered in the link?