# Upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS now cannot print

Tags: printing

I have tried everything (HPLIP, CUPS, cleaned disk, etc.) and cannot print to my old HP Deskjet D1660 (still supported).

[image: Screenshot]

The screenshot shows I need to open firewall ports, but why should I have to do this for a local printer?  Maybe I just need to add memory?  When I was upgrading the machine was fussing about the available space.  Please dumb-down your answers.

I tried running

```
sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
```

but it did not work.

I ran

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgs9-common
```

with some luck.  The printer responds but with only blank pages.  I have ink, reinstalled printer from every angle and still nothing.  Any suggestions would be great.

Thank You

Hello,

Zanna your edit did nothing to help me.  Please do not provide me any more assistance.

Thank You

Comment: Zanna is a highly respected member of this community. She works hard editing questions for others and has posted many great answers. She even voted to reopen your question after after it was closed as a duplicate. There's an old saying: *"don't bite the hand that feeds you"*....